# Example of torsion in orientable manifolds?

Tags: homology

An orientable manifold can have torsion in its integer homology.  But I believe  by Poincare duality the manifold must be at least 4-dimensional -- isn't that right?  Anyway are there simple examples of such torsion?

Comment: Three-dimensional lens spaces often have nontrivial torsion in $H_1$ over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $RP^3$ is a simple example as well.

Comment: @JohnPardon I learned of lens spaces from Seifert and Threlfall when I first began learning of homology and I did not know what mattered about them so I did not retain much.  They include $\mathbb{RP}^3$ and a quick introduction is http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Lens_spaces:_a_history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $PSU(2)$, the three-dimensional projective special unitary group (or just $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^3$). It is a Lie group, and therefore orientable. Yet, it is the quotient of the simply-connected group $SU(2)$ by its center $\mathbb{Z}_2$, so it has 2-torsion in homology.

Comment: I think this example would be more recognizable as $\mathbb{RP}^3$.

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  Yes.  I can picture  $\mathbb{RP}^3$.  But let me check my picture: the torsion 2-cycle is the natural projective plane in $\mathbb{RP}^3$, right?

Comment: The torsion is in the homology group in dimension 1, not in $H_2$. For a closed n-manifold M, Poincaré duality and the Universal Coefficient theorem imply that $H_{n-1}(M)$ is torsion-free.  Presumably that's what you were thinking of in your original question.  In this case, the torsion 1-cycle is the $RP^1$ in $RP^3$.